# How can I search using PHP through an XML file and display the results?

Tags: php, xml, search

I am trying to build a very simple price comparison script.

Until now, I wrote a code that gets some product xml feeds from shops and with the help of XSLT I create a single-global xml of all those input XMLs. I use the XSLT because the shops have different names for elements.

Now I want to take it one step further and I want to create a search form that will display me the products let's say I have the term "laptop".

I know how to create a form, but I need a coding guidance to understand how to make it to search in my XML file (products.xml) and display let's say the

Thank you

Comment: You search a php html parser ?

Comment: See: [Searching XML for Keywords](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3556975/searching-xml-feeds-for-keywords#3557094)

Comment: http://www.kirupa.com/web/xml_php_parse_beginner.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to check out http://php.net/manual/en/class.xmlreader.php

Using that it is pretty easy to navigate through an XML file and grab all the info you need.

EDIT:
On second thought, http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php is a MUCH simpler way to achieve what you're trying to do. Hence the name, I guess ;)

Comment: Hi there, I came across this earlier, because I am not an advanced programmer and I go step by step, is this an alternative for DOM or SimpleXML ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [SimpleXML](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_xml_simplexml.asp) library to parse your xml file. In my opinion SimpleXML is easier to use than xmlreader. Though SimpleXML is introduced on php5.